# JSON file modification with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a Python script to read data from a JSON file, do some calculations with it and then write output to a new JSON file. But I can't seem to automate the JSON reading process. I get this error. Could you please help me with this issue?
Thank you very much

```
print([a[0]][b[1]][c[1]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

test.json

```
{
      "male": {
            "jack": {
                  "id": "001",
                  "telephone": "+31 2225 345",
                  "address": "10 Street, Aukland",
                  "balance": "1500"
            },
            "john": {
                  "id": "002",
                  "telephone": "+31 6542 365",
                  "address": "Main street, Hanota",
                  "balance": "2500"
            }
      },

      "female": {
            "kay": {
                  "id": "00",
                  "telephone": "+31 6542 365",
                  "address": "Main street, Kiro",
                  "balance": "500"
            }
      }
}
```

test.py

```
with open("q.json") as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)

    a = ['male', 'female']
    b = ['jack', 'john', 'kay']
    c = ['id', 'telephone', 'address', 'balance']

    print([a[1]][b[1]][c[1]])
```

Comment: What do you want to print there?

Comment: @KlausD. `male -> John -> telephone`

Comment: `print(data[a[0]][b[1]][c[1]])` ? --> Note: `keys` are case sensitive

Comment: If you get json data via `data = json.load(datafile)`, `data` will be `dict` type. So you can access `male -> John -> telephone` with `data['Male']['John']['telephone']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you really want to print data from the JSON, not your intermediary arrays.

So:

```
print(data['Male'])  # will print the entire Male subsection
print(data['Male']['Jack'])  # will print the entire Jack record
print(data['Male']['Jack']['telephone'])  # will print Jack's telephone
```

But to relate that with your intermediary arrays too:

```
print(data[a[0]])  # will print the entire Male subsection
print(data[a[0]][b[0]])  # will print the entire Jack record
print(data[a[0]][b[0]][c[0]])  # will print Jack's telephone
```

assuming that you declare `a` correctly:

```
a = ['Male', 'Female']  # Notice the capitals
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I want to relate to arrays because that's how I intend to iterate through the array. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You can also iterate through the dictionary: `for key, value in data.items()`. This will give you males first, then females. iterating again through the value would give you persons and iterating again each person's details

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, how you access `data` in your code, because you directly write hard coded values into `a`, `b` and `c`. In addition, you could print out your test via: `print(a[1], b[1], c[1])`.